# High charts Change the color of horizontal bar

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9b6tvoo3/796/

```
    // create the chart
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'SOTMP Checklist Compliance History'
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },

            yAxis: {

                categories: ['Category 9',
                             'Category 8',
                             'Category 7',
                             'Category 6',
                             'Category 5',
                             'Category 4',
                             'Category 3',
                             'Category 2',
                             'Category 1'],
                tickInterval: 1,            
                tickPixelInterval: 200,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: '#525151',
                        font: '12px Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                   /* formatter: function() {
                        if (tasks[this.value]) {
                            return tasks[this.value].name;
                        }
                    }*/
                },
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Criteria'
                },
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                   fontSize:'15px'

            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ tasks[this.y].name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', this.point.options.from)  +
                        ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', this.point.options.to); 
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    lineWidth: 10,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        align: 'left',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return this.point.options && this.point.options.label;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            series: series

        });
```

And I need to change the color of first Category 3 bar to red and keep the color of second yellow, and do the same think to others categories thats have more then one horizontal bar.

What configuration should I do?

The bars need to have different colors to same category.

Thanks for attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Multicolor series plugin (using this plugin there is no need to put points in the same category to different series):

http://blacklabel.github.io/multicolor_series/

https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/33/Multicolor%20series

---

You can color your point this way:

```
series[6].data[0].segmentColor = 'blue'
```

But you have to add Multicolor series module:

```
<script src="https://blacklabel.github.io/multicolor_series/js/multicolor_series.js"></script>
```

And change your chart type to coloredline:

```
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  type: 'coloredline'
},
```

A single example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bavm762o/

And your chart: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0fudaovy/

Answer (score 0):

You can treat each individual line with two points as a series, which will allow you to easily set the color:

```
     var series = [];
     $.each(tasks.reverse(), function(i, task) {

       $.each(task.intervals, function(j, interval) {
         var item = {
           name: task.name,
           color: interval.color
         };

         item.data = [{
           x: interval.from,
           y: i,
           label: interval.label,
           from: interval.from,
           to: interval.to
         }, {
           x: interval.to,
           y: i,
           from: interval.from,
           to: interval.to
         }];

         series.push(item);
       });
     });
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mdkvsj6n/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.color